# How to execute something as soon as the data is loaded from the DB?

Tags: django, django-models, yaml

What's the best way to execute an action, such as parsing JSON or YAML from a form field, as soon as the data is loaded from the database?

My use case is: I have a model called `Puzzle` with some fields and an `data` field that contains YAML (might as well be a JSON, doesn't matter). In the code bellow, each time that I want to access a property from that YAML, I run the YAML parser and get that piece of information.

```
# models.py
import yaml

class Puzzle(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)

    data = models.TextField()

    def load_data(self):
        return yaml.load(self.data)

    @property
    def coords(self):
        d = self.load_data()
        return d['coords']

    @property
    def clues(self):
        d = self.load_data()
        return d['clues']
```

example YAML

```
coords: [[0, 0], [1, 1], [6, 8]]
clues:
    - Clue #1
    - Another Clue
# more fields, with arrays, dictionaries, etc
```

Running the parser each time the property is called is wasteful.

One possible solution is to do a simple cache: see if the YAML has been parsed before, if not, store it in some field and use that later. This introduces extra code that will be copy/pasted in each property method.

**What I'd like is to run the parser only once, when the data is queried from the DB. Overriding `__init__` in my model might work, but I'm not sure if that will break something.**

I've checked the [YAMLField](https://github.com/datadesk/django-yamlfield/), but I'm not sure if it parses the YAML data only once or not. Also, it doesn't seem to be compatible with the new migrations on Django 1.7.

Thanks!